# how to save uploaded file on elastic beanstalk?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, multer

I use a elastic-beanstalk service on AWS by using `Node.js`.
I use a `multer` for file upload and uploaded file is saved on webserver.

> But when I publish a new version of project file, the files that saved on my webserver are gone.

I want to maintain the file on webserver.
just overwrite not rewrite.

so how can I solve this issue?

**Thanks for your time!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with Elastic Beanstalk (or any auto-scaling environment), ideally you don't want to store anything on the server itself. If a user is uploading a file, save it somewhere off the server.

In AWS, this typically means storing it in S3 - this means that the file doesn't get lost when the project is updated or the server gets terminated.

Comment: That could work for regular files like PDF and so, but loading images from S3 to the web is too slow.